# Fink help!! Not installing in Mavericks!

Tags: macos, fink

I just installed OS X Mavericks on my Mac.

Now I'm trying to install Fink via the instructions [here](http://fink.thetis.ig42.org/download/srcdist.php)

I have gone up to this line command:

```
./bootstrap
```

But after that I am not able to run this line command:

```
/sw/bin/pathsetup.sh
```

... because there is no **bin** directory under **sw**.

Is it perhaps because of Mavericks (the instructions have not been updated for Mavericks because it is so new).

What can I do to fix it? (Paging Fink experts.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the version of `fink` you are using, but according to the [Fink Announcement mailing list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.os.apple.fink.announce)

> Note: be advised that fink-0.35.2 does NOT work for OS 10.9.  If you are 
>   testing on 10.9 prior to the official release date, you will want to 
>   grab an archive from https://github.com/fink/fink/tree/Futureproof2

And in the [Fink Beginners mailing list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.os.apple.fink.beginners)

> We've added support for 10.9 into the master branch of the github 
>   repository (https://github.com/fink/fink).  Folks that were using the 
>   "Futureproof2" feature branch may want to update their git checkouts 
>   appropriately to pick up changes that get made after the merge and 
>   before we do a release.
>
> Some other notes:
>
> 1. There is no 10.9 support in any released fink, version 0.35.2 or 
>      earlier.  (The first 10.9 support release version will probably be 0.36.0)
> 2. There is going to be no supported upgrade path from any earlier OS X. 
>      The document /sw/share/doc/fink/INSTALL has information about how to 
>      capture your list of installed packages.

**Update**

On October 31st, fink 0.36.0 was released which does support OS X 10.9.